# Are Azure web jobs part of Azure scheduler retirement?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-scheduler

Azure Scheduler is scheduled to retire on September 30, 2019.  Migration documentation says ["All Scheduler job collections and jobs will be deleted from the system."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/migrate-from-scheduler-to-logic-apps#faq)

In our Azure portal, webjobs are displayed under a scheduler job collection "WebJobs-NorthCentralUS". Are all these jobs going to be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web jobs won't be deleted, but the tiggers will, so they won't execute on schedule anymore.  You can set up a logic app to poke them or you can redeploy them with a cron expression.

Comment: cron expression sounds less complicated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to configure a web job to run on a schedule.

**1.** **Using Azure scheduler** - Configure a scheduler in azure portal, which points to the deployed Webjob. For more detail, refer below link.

https://nishantrana.me/2017/03/21/scheduling-a-web-job-console-application-using-azure-scheduler/

**2. Using CRON expression** - The most recommended approach for a web job scheduling. For more detail, refer below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create

Microsoft is extending the retirement date for Scheduler to December 31, 2019. You can find the updated timeline as follows:

- **On September 30, 2019** - free SKU Scheduler job collection will be disabled. Existing jobs will stop running but you can continue to retrieve data from them for migration.
- **On September 30, 2019** - the ability to create job collections will be disabled from the Azure portal for all SKUs. Existing Standard, P10, and P20 Scheduler resources will continue to run. You will also still be able to manage existing job collections.
- **On October 31, 2019** - Scheduler will be removed from the Azure portal. Existing Standard, P10, P20 Scheduler resources will continue to run, and will be accessible via API and SDKs. If you do not wish your job to continue to run after Scheduler is removed from the Azure portal, please disable or delete your job collections before October 31, 2019.
- **On December 31, 2019** - Scheduler will be fully retired. All scheduler jobs will stop running and all data will be deleted.

If you have any jobs configured on azure scheduler, please move **Azure Logic Apps** as soon as possible or you can **redeploy them with a CRON expression**.
[Migrate Azure Scheduler jobs to Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/scheduler/migrate-from-scheduler-to-logic-apps).

In addition to the Scheduler features you’re already familiar with, Logic Apps enables you to:

- Use a visual designer and connectors to integrate with more than 200 different services, including Azure Blob storage, Azure Service Bus, Microsoft Outlook, and SAP.
- Manage each scheduled workload as a first-class Azure resource.
- Run multiple one-time jobs using a single logic app.
- Set schedules that automatically adjust to daylight saving time.

Comment: I am creating webjobs with CRON, and i dont understand all this talk about scheduler. I can see it has to be retired, but there isnt any "extension due date" i haven't heard about. CRON expressions isn't a part of this, correct? I can still use CRON expressions as i understand it.

It is very hard to understand for a guy like me just starting yo use this feature of webapp.