# Azure Scheduler retirement affect webjob with CRON expression?

Tags: azure, scheduler, webjob

We know that Azure Scheduler will retire soon. So I'd Like to know if a WebJob using CRON EXPRESSION will be afected by this retirement?

Comment: that's very unlikely! WebJobs are going to stay, and so the CRON expressions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Azure web jobs part of Azure scheduler retirement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56990127/are-azure-web-jobs-part-of-azure-scheduler-retirement)

Answer (score 0):

WebJob using CRON EXPRESSION will not be affected. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create

You can also leverage Azure function and Azure Logic apps for this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#ncrontab-expressions

[Created Recurrence Trigger Logic App with the required schedule.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence)

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to configure a web job to run on a schedule.

1. **Using Azure scheduler** - Configure a scheduler in azure portal, which points to the deployed Webjob. For more detail, refer below link.

https://nishantrana.me/2017/03/21/scheduling-a-web-job-console-application-using-azure-scheduler/

Azure Logic Apps is replacing Azure Scheduler, which is being retired.

2. **Using CRON expression** - The most recommended approach for a web job scheduling. For more detail, refer below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create

So WebJob using CRON EXPRESSION will not be affected. You can still find the CRON Expression option in azure poratl as below

[image]